# Option binding is not working with bootstrap class="selectpicker" knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I am trying to use bootstrap selectpicker with knockout.js option binding.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-bind="options: responseData,optionsText: 'categoryName',optionsValue: 'categoryId',optionsCaption: ' ---- select ...'">
```

If I don't use the class selectpicker the binding is working perfectly. However, it doesn't work if I use the class.

Found this link http://jsfiddle.net/c2gbak5m/2/ but not working on my case.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found that worked for me.

```
var CategoryViewModel = {
    responseData: ko.observableArray(),
    selectCategory: ko.observable()
   }

ko.bindingHandlers.selectPicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            if ($(element).is('select')) {
                if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                    if ($(element).prop('multiple') && $.isArray(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()))) {
                        // in the case of a multiple select where the valueAccessor() is an observableArray, call the default Knockout selectedOptions binding
                        ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
                    } else {
                        // regular select and observable so call the default value binding
                        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
                    }
                }
                $(element).addClass('selectpicker').selectpicker();
            }
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            if ($(element).is('select')) {
                var isDisabled = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().disable);
                if (isDisabled) {
                    // the dropdown is disabled and we need to reset it to its first option
                    $(element).selectpicker('val', $(element).children('option:last').val());
                }
                // React to options changes
                ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor.get('options'));
                // React to value changes
                ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor.get('value'));
                // Wait a tick to refresh
                setTimeout(() => { $(element).selectpicker('refresh'); }, 0);
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the Html

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-bind="selectPicker:true, options:responseData, value:selectCategory,optionsText:'categoryName',optionsValue:'categoryId', optionsCaption: ' ---Select Category---'">    
                                    </select>
```